# C# Send file (excel) via slack

Tags: c#, file, share, slack

I need to share/send files via slack.
I created an app, and I can send message successfully, but I can send files

This is my code

```
var client1 = new SlackClient("https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        var slackMessage = new SlackMessage
        {
            Channel = "#test",
            Text = "test",
            IconEmoji = Slack.Webhooks.Emoji.Octocat,                
        };

         client1.Post(slackMessage);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't send file through slack webhook as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742775/is-it-possible-to-post-files-to-slack-using-the-incoming-webhook)

Here you have thread with examples how to do that by [slack files api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700294/post-message-with-file-attached-on-slack)

```
public void UploadFile(string token, string filePath, string channel)
{
var client = new RestClient("https://slack.com");

var request = new RestRequest("api/files.upload", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("token", token);
request.AddParameter("channels", channel);

var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
request.AddFile("file", File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), fileInfo.Name, contentType:"multipart/form-data");

//Execute the request
var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
}
```

by @ive2